# How to wait for ther page to load when the page is actually a method?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a number of methods in my selenium scripts which basically just calls a new page i.e. ChooseUserMgt();.  What pageload/waits/explicit/implicit waits can apply to ensure it launches sucessfullly because sometimes it takes to long to load?

```
 [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _regRep = new UserRegRep(driver);
            CreateRepos();
            runTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddHHmmssfff");
            userName = "Jonny" + objCommon.RandomString(8, true);
            emailID = "JonnySmithy" + runTime + "@hotmail.com";

            // Start the user mangaement tests on the user management page
            **ChooseUserMgt();**
        }
```

This is the method:

```
[TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Cat1")]
        public void ChooseUserMgt()
        {
            //Choose the User Managment menu
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", _regRep.SystemIcon);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor1.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", _regRep.UserMgmtLink);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a different approach altogether.

For clicking, i would want two methods - WaitForControlToBeClickable and Click.

The first method is to make sure the element is visible. This can get reused in all your other action methods you will need.

```
  static bool WaitForControlToBeClickable(By SeleniumObject, int waitFor = 10)
        {
            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitFor));
                wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(SeleniumObject));
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                return false;
                throw er;
            }

        }
```

Next you'll make a method to click and call the previous method inside:

```
        public void Click(By SeleniumObject)
        {
            WaitForControlClickable(SeleniumObject);
            driver.FindElement(SeleniumObject).Click();
        }
```

You can store these in another class - CommonActions. So once you instantiate that in your test you can call it like this:

```
commonAction.Click(MyObject);
```

I also recommend storing your objects in an object repository separately that you call with your actions to create tests.

Comment: Sorry @Staindz where in your code is the actual method I want to call.  Sorry newbie to c#